# Who knows what? / Who knows him?

Tags: phrase-meaning

For example, we have a father who tries to keep her daughter from some mistakes and he knows that their neighbour's boy have a crush on her daughter. Which phrase would be more idiomatic in this case and why:

> I’m watching him. **Who knows what?**
>
> I’m watching him. **Who knows him?**

P.S. If you need another example in order to explain the difference, please, do it.

Comment: You haven't really asked a question - what are actually you trying to say? Have you looked up the meanings of the two? Is something else meant to follow the ellipsis?

Comment: There isn't a question here (you need to actually assign a meaning to the ellipses), but I would say that "who knows him" is unlikely to be correct in this context.

Comment: There is nothing, it's just a way to ask a meaningful question.

Comment: I'm sure this question will soon be closed (as "Opinion-Based"), but I suspect the matter of what anyone might ***know*** about the boy isn't relevant. All the cited speaker is trying to say is ***I don't trust him*** (in context, probably the father *specifically* doesn't trust the boy next door not to land his daughter with an unwanted pregnancy! :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm just trying to remember how many people it takes to tango.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: As in *the cited speaker is trying to say **I don't trust my daughter**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Very possibly. Outside of rape, it generally needs two people to make the kind of 'mistake' that makes a baby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither "I'm watching him. Who knows what?" nor "...Who knows him?" are idiomatic, and I would say they are not grammatically correct (in this context) either.

Usually, the phrase "Who knows *X*?" requires that *X* be a question word (who, what, where, when, why, how). Further, unless it is blindingly obvious from the preceding context, the phrase needs to continue with some *thing*:

- Who knows **why** *the caged bird sings*?
- Who knows **where** *the time goes*?
- Who knows **how much** *I love you*?

(Those examples were all pulled from google search autocomplete suggestions.)

You can use "who knows *X*?" where *X* is a direct object and not a question word:

- Who knows *mommy [or other person] best*?

---

In your example, what you are implying is

> I'm watching him. Who knows **what** *he will do [or is capable of doing]*?

The idiomatic way of saying this is either to say the whole phrase as above, or to say "You know him" which is shorthand for "You know what he's like/what he might do."

Comment: As I understand it, also there is possible to say "Who knows what will happen?" or "Who knows what might happen?"

Comment: @Sergey, yes, that is what I said in the first part of my answer. But just "Who knows what?" on its own would not be natural in this context.